# Water dripping from a gas vent thats connected to my furnace

Tags: water, furnace, vent, leaking

I just noticed when I opened the closet where my furnace is located there was water in the middle. It appears to be leaking from 2 spots on a vent that's labeled the (gas vent connector) its sunday and we are currently in a snow storm. Does anyone know why this would be leaking? Is it safe for a few days untill I can have someone fix? It had to just recently happen. That closet I kept Christmas gifts and it was fine then. I put a bucket under the 2 spots I can here it from upstairs just a drip. I think it drips after the heat shuts off because when I was down there cleaning it up the heat never came on and it never dripped.

Comment: Is it an 80% or 90% furnace or something else? If not sure, model # would tell us. Does it vent through metal or plastic? Water is a natural product of gas combustion. Depending on design, you may have a usual path for that water (drain pipe, condensate pump, etc.) and that may be clogged so it then takes the next available path...into your closet.

Comment: Apparently you have a high efficiency furnace with plastic pipe for combustion exhaust. The plastic pipe must be installed with the correct pitch to not leak back into the house.  The pipe was incorrectly installed or it has been moved. Generally a utility closet is not a good place for storage.

Comment: Its metal vent. The house was built in 2009 it's been there since. I just bought it in 2020. I dont keep storage in the closet. At Christmas I kept a few small things to hide from my son. I was getting a curtain that I used to cover the items up that's how I noticed the leak. I believe what it is after doing some research is the vent where it seals together is leaking probably due to age. There is a label I took a pic of that is on the vent. I will see if there is any numbers on it.

Comment: Part number 150098 double wall gas connector vent. Its a sloped vent. 2 areas where it connects vent pieces is dripping. There is a white build up on one of the spots. I am definitely not going to fix this myself. Just wanted to make sure it's ok till I get someone to look at it.

Comment: What make/model is your furnace?

Comment: The only thing I see telling me that info is. RHEEM Classic super quit 80 series.

Comment: Adding a clear, focused picture or two showing where the drips are coming from (a general overview pic and a close up of the leaking spot(s)) would be quite helpful, as well.

Comment: How can I add a picture? Also I think now I see its actually starting from the roof. Where that vent goes outside we had a leak right after we moved in had someone come over and repair it. It looks like water is getting in the vent and coming out where the vent connects together if I can show a picture it would be easier to explain. I called the place today told them what's going on there are supposed to get back to me when they can come out.